# Fresco Library Not Loading Any Images

Tags: java, android, fresco

So due to memory issue I thought about using Facebook's Fresco library.

So this is what I did,

First I added the following dependencies,

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
```

Then I initialized it in application class,

```
Fresco.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then I added SimpleDraweeView to layout file,

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/imageMessage"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    />
```

Then I added the code in my activity,

```
        SimpleDraweeView gif = (SimpleDraweeView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageMessage);

        ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource (Uri.parse(url.get(position)))
                .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled (true)
                .build ();
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder ()
                .setImageRequest (request)
                .setAutoPlayAnimations (true)

                .build ();

        gif.setController (controller);
```

But it's not loading images, I also tried different urls but same result, So what I'm missing...

Comment: You have requested internet permissions right?

Comment: Yeah @Eenvincible

Comment: Where is the image coming from?

Comment: From my server. I also tried some other images from random google search and same result, So I think in that case there is no problem @Eenvincible

Comment: I have not used this library before but I would like to see a documentation

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue but not with gif. below is the code which load images, don't forget to initialize fresco.

```
       Fresco.initialize(context);

         SimpleDraweeView  iv_image = (SimpleDraweeView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
         iv_image.setImageURI(Uri.parse("your image url here"));
```

`

and here is xml

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/iv_car"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.22"/>
```